# "Could not locate Java 6 or 7 SDK" Visual Studio 2015 issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I keep getting this error when I try and build the project ("*Could not locate Java 6 or 7  SDK*").

I know there are a couple of posts regarding this here, but I did everything that needs to be done (*install version 6 32-bit because I own Windows 7 64-bit, edit environment variables, change the path in Tools -> Options -> Xamarin, restart the machine*...) and it still doesn't work.

Build output logs are as follows: [Build output logs](https://pastebin.com/kHcpBzKP)

```
Version:
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.6.01055
```

Please, help.

Comment: Please include any relevant build output logs and your version information. JDK 8 is the current needed JDK.

Comment: @JonDouglas I have included both. My first installation included JDK 8 but I had the same error. That's why I've switched to 6 and 7, but to no avail.

Comment: What path is your JDK on? Can you try to move it to a non-space, no special characters path?

Comment: @JonDouglas My JDK is on "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45". I've tried installing it in both, Program Files and Program Files (x86) but the result stays the same. Can you clarify what you meant by "no special characters path?"

Comment: That is a 1.6 version of the JDK(Very Old). please download a 1.8 version and point Visual Studio to it.

Comment: @JonDouglas I confirm that I have downloaded the latest 1.8 version, installed it on C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161 and pointed Visual Studio to it. It gave me a green checkmark, but the error remains even after restarting both the Visual Studio and the machine itself.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Visual Studio, you can choose what SDK's to install. Try to run Visual Studio installation again and see if you can find "Java 6/7 SDK" in it. I don't quite remember where to look for it, since I haven't used VS for a while, but it should be somewhere there. Good luck

Comment: Already checked that more than a couple of times. Everything seems to be in order. It even says that the appropriate JDK has already been installed, but I keep getting the same problem.

Comment: @IMug3tsu thats weird. How about uninstalling Visual Studio completely. Restarting your PC and starting over?

Comment: I will give it a shot.

Comment: @IMug3tsu Good luck! Sometimes crap like this happens, and usually its very simples fixes such this.

Comment: Sadly, true... I'll let you know how it went!

Answer (score 0):

Install JDK for Windows x86 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Then goto visual studio 2015 tools > options > xamarian > android settings and configure the Java development kit location C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\

Now clean and rebuild the solution.

In visual studio click "Open Android emulator manager" and start the emulator. Wait for sometime for the OS to load. Once android is loaded run the project.

[screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrSwz.png)